# How to create a table of data in my MySQL using laravel5.5?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am trying to create mysql tables in Laravel 5.5 I created a file in /project/database/migrations/MY_migration_file.php

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class MY_migration_file extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('chaves',function (Blueprint $table){
            $table -> increments('id');
            $table -> string('nome');
            $table -> boolean('alugado');
            $table -> timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

however, my mysql5.7 database is not receiving data from my migration (it's empty) file. What should I do ?

Comment: How did you create the migration file? did you used the artisan command?

Comment: Did you migrate it?  php artisan migrate?

Comment: Is your database configured properly in your .env file?

Comment: What error you are getting when run php artisan migrate?

Comment: Try by using clear cache

Comment: @JesusErwinSuarez, I created the migration file, which is what I put in the description of the post.

Comment: @Serge, the php command artisan migrate says: nothing to migrate. my .env is setup correctly.

Comment: @JinandraGupta, I used php artisan cache:clear

Comment: @JinandraGupta,I did not have any errors, just say: nothing to migrate

Comment: try composer dump autoload then migrate again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not a good idea to create migration with different name, this will become confusing in the long run.

Try using the artisan command to generate the migration file

```
   php artisan make:migration create_chaves_table --create=chaves
```

This will create **date_create_chaves_table.php**

Add this column in your newly created **date_create_chaves_table.php** like this.

```
    Schema::create('chaves',function (Blueprint $table){
        $table -> increments('id');
        $table -> string('nome');
        $table -> boolean('alugado');
        $table -> timestamps();
    });
```

And run this command

```
php artisan migrate
```

That should do the migration of your new table.

Hope that helps.

Comment: My pleasure to help @ivo

Answer (score 0):

If you have made changes for DB connection in .env file. Please run artian command:

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan optimize
```